# How to show file save file dialog box while click download button?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to show dialog box to save the file (to select the path where you want to save the file) while clicking the download button using PrimeFaces. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't that normally a browser setting that determines that? i.e. you won't get a prompt if you set a default download location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Don't know if it might be suitable in your specific case, but you can set the `content-disposition` HTTP header to `attachment` in the response in order to hint the browser to show the _save as_ dialog. See [19.5.1 Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) of the HTTP spec.

Comment: @Xavi: this is controlled via the `contentDisposition` attribute of the PrimeFaces file download tag.

Comment: Great, not familiar with JSF at the moment, but I was already assuming any decent framework would have a way to provide it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The PrimeFaces `<p:fileDownload>` tag](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/fileDownload.html) has the `contentDisposition` attribute for that which you could set to `inline` (to display the file inline) or `attachment` (to pop a *Save As* dialogue).

```html
<p:fileDownload ... contentDisposition="attachment" />
```

However, it defaults to `attachment` already! You shouldn't have the need to explicitly specify it.

So your concrete problem is caused by your webbrowser itself. Most modern webbrowsers can be configured to take specific default actions when a file of a specific content type is been retrieved. Apparently yours is configured to always display it inline regardless of the content disposition. It's unclear which webbrowser you're using, but the way how Firefox handles it is the most commonly known and confusing among starters, so I'll target my answer on it.

When you download for example a PDF file in Firefox, it'll by default show you a dialog with 2 options: open it (inline) in Adobe, or save it to disk. Below that, there's a checkbox to remember the default action.

[image]

Apparently you've ever ticked that while the option is set to open the file inline and this way Firefox will never ask you anymore whether to open or to save it.

You can reconfigure this by *Tools > Options > Applications*.

[image]

Comment: sry i'm using  contentDisposition="attachment".but not working in  chrome and  also firefox.

Comment: Did you *read and understand* the answer? :) Try to read the text as well instead of only looking at the 1st block of code.

Comment: In chrome Setting --> show advance setting --> Downloads -->select Ask where to save each file before downloading